# zend framework form upload edit problem

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms, upload, populate

I am uploading pictures using zend form.

my problem is when editing the information in the form the form comes with all the information, but the file_path is empty so when you click submit the update that happen set the file_path null.

i just want to view the path of the editable item when loading so when you click submit the old path will be there.

```
public function EditaddAction() {

    $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('user');
    $userid = $session->id;
    // in case the request was an edit request
    $id = (int) $this->_request->getParam('id');
    //The incoming request
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    //initialize form
    $form = new Admin_Form_Banner();
    //uploaded file settings
    $file = $form->file_path;
    $file->setDestination(ZendX_Image::getFullUploadPath() . '/files/get/original/');
    //instance of db
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {

            $dbFilePath = "/files/get/original/" . $file->getFileName(null, false);


            //code to get the duration of the video
            $sourceVideo = PUBLIC_PATH . $form->getValue('file_path');
            ob_start();
            passthru("ffmpeg -i \"" . $sourceVideo . "\" 2>&1");
            $duration = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
            preg_match('/Duration: (.*?),/', $duration, $matches);
            $duration = $matches[1];
            $duration_array = preg_split('[:]', $duration);
            $duration = $duration_array[0] * 3600 + $duration_array[1] * 60 + $duration_array[2];

            die($time);
            end of code to get the duration of the video
            if (isset($id) && $id != "" && $file->receive()) {
                try {
                    $db->update('banner', array('banner_title' => $form->getValue('banner_title'),
                        'banner_type' => $form->getValue('banner_type'),
                        'banner_position' => $form->getValue('banner_position'),
                        'banner_link' => $form->getValue('banner_link'),
                        'link_open' => $form->getValue('link_open'),
                        'file_path' => $dbFilePath,
                        'is_active' => $form->getValue('is_active')
                            ), array('id =?' => $id));
                    $this->flash('Banner Updated', 'admin/banner');
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $this->flash($e->getMessage(), 'admin/banner');
                }
            } else {
                try {

                    $db->insert('banner', array('banner_title' => $form->getValue('banner_title'),
                        'banner_type' => $form->getValue('banner_type'),
                        'banner_position' => $form->getValue('banner_position'),
                        'banner_link' => $form->getValue('banner_link'),
                        'link_open' => $form->getValue('link_open'),
                        'file_path' => $dbFilePath,
                        'is_active' => $form->getValue('is_active'),
                        'created_by' => $userid,
                        'date_ceated' => date('Y/m/d H:i:s'),
                        'is_deleted' => 0,
                    ));
                    $this->flash('Banner Added', 'admin/banner');
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $this->flash($e->getMessage(), 'admin/banner');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (isset($id) && $id != "") {
        $checkvalues = $db->fetchCol($db->select()->from(array('banner'),array('file_path')));
        $values = $db->fetchRow("SELECT * FROM banner WHERE id = ?", $id);
        $values['file_path'] = $checkvalues;
        $form->populate($values);
    }

    $this->view->form = $form;
```

Comment: I would edit that description to be multiple sentences and paragraphs so that people have a chance of reading it!

Comment: On update don't override the value in the database unless it has been provided?

Comment: i did that still same problem

Comment: you cannot get the users local file path if that is what you are after.

Comment: now i dont want the user local file path i want the file path on my project public

Answer (score 1):

When you say path you mean the path in http client?
You don't have access to that.

If your problem is about the path to the file after uploading you can do as following:

1) the element must be a Zend_Form_Element_File.

2) in controller:

```
$form->file_path->receive(); //this will return true if the file was successfully received and false if not
$file_path_on_server = $form->file_path->getFileName(); // there you get the file name
```

The file will keep its original name.

Comment: when i try your first code and var_dump it. i got a false message it means it is retrieving nothing do you know why ?

Comment: A false means the file wasn't received successfully. Don't forget to set destination of Zend_Form_Element_File (_$element->setDestination('path')_)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.
I solved it by using a hidden field, in the form, in which I store the file name and use it in the modify action

```
some action code
if ($request->isPost()) {
                if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {
                    if ('administrator' == $user->role) {
                        $oldFileName = $form->getElement('oldfilename')->getValue(); //the hidden field
                        $data = $form->getValues();
                        $model->populate($data);
                    if (file_exists('uploads/cv/' . $oldFileName)) {
                            $form->getElement('cv')->setIgnore(true); //this is my Form File Element - the file exists, I don't need to store the filename
                        } else { // if you want you can unlink $oldFileName
                            $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
                            $info = $upload->getFileInfo('cv');
                            $upload->setDestination("uploads/cv/");
                            if (file_exists('uploads/cv/' . $info['cv']['name'])) {
                                $newFileName = time() . rand(0, 100000) . "-" . $info['cv']['name']; // I need to avoid overwriting file
                            } else {
                                $newFileName = $info['cv']['name'];
                                $upload->addFilter('Rename', $newFileName);
                            }
                            try {
                                $upload->receive();
                            } catch (Zend_File_Transfer_Exception $e) {
                                $e->getMessage();
                            }
                        }
                        $model->save();
                        return $this->_helper->redirector('list');
                    } else {
                        //some error message
                        $this->_helper->redirector('list');
                    }
                } else { //form not valid
                    $this->view->form = $form;
                }
            } else {
                $model->find($id);
                $data = array();
                $data = $model->toArray();
                $data['oldfilename'] = $model->get_cv(); //the filename stored in db
                $form->getElement('cv')->setRequired(false);
                $form->populate($data);
                $this->view->form = $form;
            }
```

Surely there are many things that can be fixed for a better programming...

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function addAction()
    {

        // Criação do Objeto Formulário
        $form = new Application_Form_Banner();
        $banners = new Application_Model_Banners();
        // Há dados para Tratamento?
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

            // Pegamos os Dados como Foram Enviados
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            $path = APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/banners/';
            if (!is_dir($path)) {
                mkdir($path, 0777, true);
            }
            if ($form->isValid($data)) {

                try {
                    // Dados Filtrados pelo Formulário
                    $banners->getAdapter()->beginTransaction();
                    //gambi para renomear arquivos
                    $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
//                $upload->addValidator('Size', false, array('min' => 100,
//                    'max' => 1150000,
//                    'bytestring' => true));
                    $upload->addValidator('ImageSize', false, array(
                        'minwidth' => 10, 'minheight' => 10,
                        'maxwidth' => 5500, 'maxheight' => 5500));
                    $filename = $upload->getFilename();
                    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                    $filename = basename($filename);
                    $newfilename = mt_rand() . '.' . $ext;
                    $upload->addFilter(new Zend_Filter_File_Rename(array('target' => $path . $newfilename, 'overwrite' => false)));
                    if (!$upload->isValid()) {
                        $this->_flashMessenger->addMessage(array('error' => 'O tamanho arquivo é muito grande.'));
                    }
                    if ($upload->receive()) {

                        //Para funcionar esse metodo $form->getValues(); precisa ficar abaixo do método $upload->receive()
                        $data = $form->getValues();
                        $data['banner_imagem'] = $newfilename;
                        // Qualquer Manipulação de Dados
                        $banners->insert($data);
                        $banners->getAdapter()->commit();
                        $form->reset(); //limpa os campos do form.
                        $this->_flashMessenger->addMessage(array('success' => 'Dados salvos com sucesso!'));
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $this->_flashMessenger->addMessage(array('error' => $e->getMessage()));
                } catch (Zend_File_Transfer_Exception $e) {
                    $this->_flashMessenger->addMessage(array('error' => $e->getMessage()));
                } catch (Zend_Db_Table_Exception $e) {
                    $banners->getAdapter()->rollBack();
                    $this->_flashMessenger->addMessage(array('error' => $e->getMessage()));
                }
            } else {
                $form->populate($data);
            }
        }
        // Envio para a Camada de Visualização
        $this->view->form = $form;
    }

    public function editAction()
    {
        // Criação do Objeto Formulário
        $form = new Application_Form_Banner();
        $banners = new Application_Model_Banners();
        $form->getElement('banner_imagem')->setRequired(false);
        $form->getElement('banner_imagem')->setIgnore(true);

        $id = $this->_request->getParam('id');
        $data = $banners->find($id)->current()->toArray();
        $path = APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/banners/';
        $banner_imagemdb = $data['banner_imagem'];
//        Zend_Debug::dump( $form->getValues());
        // Há dados para Tratamento?
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

            // Pegamos os Dados como Foram Enviados
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

//            $data = $form->getValues();
//            Zend_Debug::dump($this->getRequest()->getPost());
//            print($form->getValue('banner_imagem'));
//            $banner_imagem = $form->getValue('banner_imagem');


            if (!is_dir($path)) {
                mkdir($path, 0777, true);
            }
            if ($form->isValid($data)) {
//                Zend_Debug::dump($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                try {

                    // Dados Filtrados pelo Formulário
                    $banners->getAdapter()->beginTransaction();
//                    Zend_Debug::dump($banner_imagem);
                    if ($form->banner_imagem->isUploaded()) {
                        //gambi para renomear arquivos
                        $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
                        $upload->addValidator('Size', false, array('min' => 100,
                            'max' => 11150000,
                            'bytestring' => true));
                        $upload->addValidator('ImageSize', false, array(
                            'minwidth' => 10, 'minheight' => 10,
                            'maxwidth' => 5500, 'maxheight' => 5500));
                        $filename = $upload->getFilename();
                        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                        $filename = basename($filename);
                        $newfilename = mt_rand() . '.' . $ext;
                        $upload->addFilter(new Zend_Filter_File_Rename(array('target' => $path . $newfilename, 'overwrite' => false)));
                        if (!$upload->isValid()) {
                            $this->_flashMessenger->addMessage(array('error' => 'O tamanho arquivo é muito grande.'));
                        }
                        if ($upload->receive()) {
                            //apaga imagem antiga            
                            @unlink($path . $banner_imagemdb);

                            //Para funcionar esse metodo $form->getValues(); precisa ficar abaixo do método $upload->receive()
                            $data = $form->getValues();
                            $data['banner_imagem'] = $newfilename;
                            // Qualquer Manipulação de Dados
                            $where = $banners->getAdapter()->quoteInto("banner_id = ?", $id);
                            $banners->update($data, $where);
                            $banners->getAdapter()->commit();
                            $form->reset(); //limpa os campos do form.
                            $this->_flashMessenger->addMessage(array('success' => 'Dados salvos com sucesso!'));
                        }
                    } else {
                        $form->getElement('banner_imagem')->setRequired(false);
                        $form->getElement('banner_imagem')->setIgnore(true);
                        //Para funcionar esse metodo $form->getValues(); precisa ficar abaixo do método $upload->receive()
                        $data = $form->getValues();
                        $data['banner_imagem'] = $banner_imagemdb;
                        // Qualquer Manipulação de Dados
                        $where = $banners->getAdapter()->quoteInto("banner_id = ?", $id);
                        $banners->update($data, $where);
                        $banners->getAdapter()->commit();
                        $form->reset(); //limpa os campos do form.
                        $this->_flashMessenger->addMessage(array('success' => 'Dados salvos com sucesso!'));
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $this->_flashMessenger->addMessage(array('error' => $e->getMessage()));
                } catch (Zend_File_Transfer_Exception $e) {
                    $this->_flashMessenger->addMessage(array('error' => $e->getMessage()));
                } catch (Zend_Db_Table_Exception $e) {
                    $banners->getAdapter()->rollBack();
                    $this->_flashMessenger->addMessage(array('error' => $e->getMessage()));
                }
            }
        }

//        Zend_Debug::dump($data);
        $form->populate($data);
        $imagePreview = $form->createElement('image', 'image_preview');
// element options
        $imagePreview->setLabel('Preview Image: ');
        $imagePreview->setAttrib('style', 'width:200px;height:auto;');
// add the element to the form
        $imagePreview->setOrder(4);
        $imagePreview->setImage('/public/banners/' . $data['banner_imagem']);

        $form->addElement($imagePreview);


        // Envio para a Camada de Visualização
        $this->view->form = $form;
    }

    assim da certo
```